# Python: typing: Typehints on function not working

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm having trouble getting type hints to work in the following example.  Can anyone  see what is wrong.

The 2nd and 3rd example works fine. The first one fails when i run it

```
#python 3.6
from typing import List, Tuple

# line 5 below where error occurs
def func(x: List[int, str]) -> int:
    return 1

a = func([1, "a"])

# OK
def func2(x: Tuple[int, str]) -> int:
    return 1

b = func2((1, "a"))

# OK
def func3(x: List[Union[str, int]]) -> int:
    return 1

c = func3((1, "a"))
```

Here is the stack trace.  I can't work out what is wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:scratch/scratch2.py", line 5, in <module>
    def func(x: List[int, str]) -> int:
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\typing.py", line 1152, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\typing.py", line 662, in _check_generic
    ("many" if alen > elen else "few", repr(cls), alen, elen))
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.List; actual 2, expected 1
```

Comment: The typing library will only accept one argument to the List type.

Comment: A `List` can only contain a single type.  That type may be a `Union` type: `List[Union[str, int]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typing library will only accept one argument to the List type